# Rails __elasticsearch__.create_index! "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters(mapper_parsing_exception)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I have trouble with *elasticsearch-rails*, when I'm using `Business.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` I'm getting an error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [business : {dynamic=true, properties={id={type=integer}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [business : {dynamic=true, properties={id={type=integer}}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [business : {dynamic=true, properties={id={type=integer}}}]"}},"status":400}

Behind that request is:

> PUT http://localhost:9200/development_businesses [status:400, request:0.081s, query:N/A]
>   {"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1}},"mappings":{"business":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer"}}}}}

My Model code:

```
`
after_save :reindex_model
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], log: true
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
index_name [Rails.env, model_name.collection.gsub('///', '-')].join('_')
document_type self.name.downcase
`
```

I have defined my mapping:

```
`
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'true' do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    end
end
`
```

Comment: If you are using version 7.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629372/reindex-error-when-upgrading-to-elasticsearch-7/58629523#58629523

Comment: what about `"dynamic":"true"` ?

Comment: I tried both true and false but no effect @Sunny

Comment: @AhmadAli have a look on my given answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the part `{"business":{"dynamic":"true"`}} while creating the mapping. Try like below that works fine for me-

```
PUT /development_businesses/
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can remove dynamic: 'true', but how I can remove 'business' using rails code.

Comment: @AhmadAli brother I not familiar with ruby that's why couldn't help you here

Comment: Your answer is right @Sunny and as in my case, I removed document_type from my Model class, and now everything works fine.

Comment: @AhmadAli glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

As of ES 7, mapping types have been removed. You can read more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

If you are using Ruby On Rails this means that you may need to remove `document_type` from your model or concern.

As an alternative to mapping types one solution is to use an index per document type.

Before:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
    index_name [Rails.env, Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.underscore].join('_')
    document_type self.name.downcase
  end
end
```

After:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
    index_name [Rails.env, Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.underscore, self.name.downcase].join('_')
  end
end
```